# Having Trouble filling a LocalDateTime array with data from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, localdatetime

I'm using a MySQL database to hold information for my reminder application in Java. I'm trying to pull the information out and store it in an array and the compare each element of the array to an updating current timestamp. The issue is the code I have gives a nullpointer exception and I can't figure out why. It works when the LocalDateTime isn't an array but the moment I turn it into an array it throws the error. It also demands I initialize it to null over anything else.

Thoughts on how I can fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Here's the method in question.

```
public static LocalDateTime[] getReminderTime()
{
    String SQL = "SELECT r_dateTime FROM reminder_database.reminder;";
    LocalDateTime reminderTime[] = null;
    try 
    {
        Connection conn = main.getConnection();

        java.sql.Statement stmt;
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        if(rs.isBeforeFirst())
        {
            for(int i = 0; rs.next(); i++)
            {
                reminderTime[i] = rs.getTimestamp(1).toLocalDateTime();
            }
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown with getReminderTime --> " + e + e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return reminderTime;
}
```

Heres the exception thrown

```
Exception thrown with getReminderTime --> java.lang.NullPointerException[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@6dfc1e5f
Exception thrown with getReminderTime --> java.lang.NullPointerException[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@3b2da18f
```

Comment: please add the complete error code/traceback.

Comment: Added the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

I needed to initialize a size for the array in order to fill it. So I created another method that went through all the elements and gets the size.

Here's the code.

```
public static LocalDateTime[] getReminderTime()
{
    String SQL = "SELECT r_dateTime FROM reminder_database.reminder;";
    LocalDateTime reminderTime[] = null;
    reminderTime = new LocalDateTime[getSizeOfRs()];
    try 
    {
        Connection conn = main.getConnection();

        java.sql.Statement stmt;
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);


        if(rs.isBeforeFirst())
        {

            for(int i = 0; rs.next(); i++)
            {
                reminderTime[i] = rs.getTimestamp(1).toLocalDateTime();

            }
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown with getReminderTime --> " + e +  e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return reminderTime;
}
```

and the get rs size

```
public static int getSizeOfRs()
{

    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM reminder_database.reminder;";
    int size = 0;
    try {
        Connection conn = main.getConnection();

        java.sql.Statement stmt;
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);


        for(int i = 0; rs.next(); i++)
            size++;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown with getSizeofRS --> " + e +  e.getStackTrace());
    }

    return size;
}
```